# Loading an Image generated from an array into a wxpython frame

Tags: python, image, image-processing, wxpython, medical

I am trying to get produce a programme to display DICOM images and move through slices using event buttons. I want to test it first on moving through the z-slices of a np.array. The code is based on an example file viewer online.

How can i get the test button to call up the randomly generated image?

I have simplified the code to only show one 200x200 pixel array and not to travel through slices, but it still cant display the generated image.

```py
import os
import wx
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

data = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 255, size =(200, 200)) #generation of random array
test_img = Image.fromarray(data.astype('uint8')) #turn array into image

class PhotoCtrl(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Slice Viewer')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self.frame) 
        self.PhotoMaxSize = 200 
        self.createWidgets()
        self.frame.Show()

    def createWidgets(self):
        instructions = 'Browse for an image'
        img = wx.EmptyImage(200,200)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                         wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        instructLbl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=instructions)
        self.photoTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(100,-1))
        browseBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Browse')
        browseBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBrowse)

        up_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Up')
        up_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press_up) 

        down_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Down')
        down_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press_down)

        test_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Test')
        test_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onViewTest)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.mainSizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(instructLbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.imageCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.photoTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(browseBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)   
        self.mainSizer.Add(up_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(down_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(test_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self.frame)

        self.panel.Layout()

    def onBrowse(self, event):
        """ 
        Browse for file mode for later testing
        """
        wildcard = "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file",
                               wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.FD_OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.photoTxt.SetValue(dialog.GetPath())
        dialog.Destroy() 
        self.onView()

    def onView(self):
        """
        Part of later data selection
        """
        filepath = self.photoTxt.GetValue()
        img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        # scale the image, preserving the aspect ratio
        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()
        if W > H:
            NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize
            NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize
            NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize * W / H
        img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)

        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()

    def onViewTest(self):
        """
        Problem code area, trying to call the generated image and display
        """
        img = wx.Image(test_img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()

    def on_press_up(self, event):
        print('up')

    def on_press_down(self, event):
        print('down')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PhotoCtrl()
    app.MainLoop()

del app
'''

Currently i get a positional argument error, but don't understand why as the browse function works with only one argument.
```

Comment: You forgot that it is an `event` driven subroutine. `onViewTest(self, event)`

Comment: If you are using wx.python 4, you have other issues with the test image and if you fail to select a file from the dialog. If you're on wx 2.8 you may get away with the image creation problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code amended for wxpython 4.0.4 with python 3
You'll note:

> A change in how the test image is generated
>   A change to the `if` statement when selecting an image file
>   The `def` of `onViewTest`

Hopefully these changes will give you what you want.
If you are still using wxPython 2.8 you may need to retain some of your existing image manipulations, as wxPython 4+ has changed a few of these.

```
import os
import wx
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

data = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 255, size =(200, 200)) #generation of random array
#test_img = Image.fromarray(data.astype('uint8')) #turn array into image

class PhotoCtrl(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Slice Viewer')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self.frame)
        self.PhotoMaxSize = 200
        self.createWidgets()
        self.frame.Show()

    def createWidgets(self):
        instructions = 'Browse for an image'
        img = wx.Image(200,200)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY,
                                         wx.Bitmap(img))

        instructLbl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=instructions)
        self.photoTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(100,-1))
        browseBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Browse')
        browseBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBrowse)

        up_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Up')
        up_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press_up)

        down_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Down')
        down_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press_down)

        test_btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Test')
        test_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onViewTest)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.mainSizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(instructLbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.imageCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.photoTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(browseBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(up_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(down_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(test_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self.frame)

        self.panel.Layout()

    def onBrowse(self, event):
        """
        Browse for file mode for later testing
        """
        wildcard = "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file",
                               wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.FD_OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.photoTxt.SetValue(dialog.GetPath())
            dialog.Destroy()
            self.onView()

    def onView(self):
        """
        Part of later data selection
        """
        filepath = self.photoTxt.GetValue()
        img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        # scale the image, preserving the aspect ratio
        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()
        if W > H:
            NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize
            NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize
            NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize * W / H
        img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)

        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()

    def onViewTest(self, event):
        """
        Problem code area, trying to call the generated image and display
        """
#        img = wx.Image(test_img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
#        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        img = wx.Image(200,200)
        img.SetData(data)
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()

    def on_press_up(self, event):
        print('up')

    def on_press_down(self, event):
        print('down')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PhotoCtrl()
    app.MainLoop()

del app
```

[image: Your random test image]

Your "random" test image being displayed

Comment: What has caused the appearance of the test image to change? Obviously its in RGB but why has it become columned in that way, and is there away to change it, as when proper data is used it will result in a loss of information.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. I don't use `PIL` or `numpy` personally. If you use `img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')` and then `img.show()` you will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a positional argument error because the method **def onViewTest(self):** needs a second argument, for example **def onViewTest(self, event):**

The second error is that the variable **test_img** is requiring a string to the filepath of the image.  You can do something like the following:

```
def onView(self):
    """
    Part of later data selection
    """
    filepath = self.photoTxt.GetValue()
    self.filepath = filepath
```

and then

```
def onViewTest(self, event):
    """
    Fixed code area, to call the generated image and display
    """
    img = wx.Image(self.filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
```

That all fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the 'event', addition, it has stopped the first error. I don't think this resolves how to get the generated image to display. How would adding a file path help this as it is generated in the code and is not save to a directory?